# Are there any other classes like SPBuiltInFieldId and SPBuiltInContentTypeId?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

Are there any other built-in classes similar to [SPBuiltInFieldId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid_fields.aspx) and [SPBuiltInContentTypeId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid_fields.aspx)?

I am creating a feature that will be deployed to both English and Polish site collections. It **uses a custom Web Service** - when I need to access some list or Web Part, **I have to check the current language and use a proper name** ("Site Template Gallery" or "Galeria szablonów witryn", "Site Image" or "Obraz witryny").

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
SPList list = pubSite.RootWeb.GetCatalog(SPListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
```

is that something like what you´re looking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx

Otherwise if you´re looking for a way to get the list by its internal name you can have a look at this post instead: 
http://johanleino.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6BE273C70C45B5D1!294.entry

**UPDATE:**

If you need to get a resource from 12\Template\Resources you can use something like:

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources: dcl_schema_view_allitems", "core", 1053);
```

This will get the value from the key **dcl_schema_view_allitems** from the core.resx with swedish locale. Edit to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, SPListTemplateType won't work, since many list can use the same list template; the 2nd link looked promising, but internal name in this case unfortunately means the URL of the list, so it's rather cumbersome, too (e.g. the URL of Site Template Gallery is /_catalogs/wt/ - not very intuitive).

Answer (score 1):

So your question is more along the lines of **"How can I find the name of a SharePoint artifact in another language?"**

There are two main locations:

1. `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\Resources`
2. The App_GlobalResources subfolder of the IIS web site that SharePoint is using. For example: `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\App_GlobalResources`

The resource files are all XML. Find the text you need in the language you are most comfortable with and make a note of the XML node details. Then open the file for the other language(s) and use XPath, LINQ or your favourite XML technology to read the corresponding value in that language.